# P6 Architecture - Register renaming aside, does the limited user registers result in more ops spent spilling/loading?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-architecture, compiler-theory

I'm studying JIT design with regard to dynamic languages VM implementation. I haven't done much Assembly since the 8086/8088 days, just a little here or there, so be nice if I'm out of sorts.

As I understand it, the x86 (IA-32) architecture still has the same basic limited register set today that it always did, but the internal register count has grown tremendously, but these internal registers are not generally available and are used with register renaming to achieve parallel pipelining of code that otherwise could not be parallelizable. I understand this optimization pretty well, but my feeling is, while these optimizations help in overall throughput and for parallel algorithms, the limited register set we are still stuck with results in more register spilling overhead such that if x86 had double, or quadruple the registers available to us, there may be significantly less push/pop opcodes in a typical instruction stream? Or are there other processor optmizations that also optimize this away that I am unaware of? Basically if I've a unit of code that has 4 registers to work with for integer work, but my unit has a dozen variables, I've got potentially a push/pop for every 2 or so instructions.

Any references to studies, or better yet, personal experiences?

EDIT: x86_64 has 16 registers, which is double x86-32, thanks for the correction and info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to renaming registers to hide bubbles due to instruction latencies, most x86 architectures are smart enough to count pushes and pops and rename those onto registers as well.  Remember that the instruction decoder on the x86 actually performs a sort of JIT compilation, turning the x86 instruction stream into a small microcode program stored in the trace cache. Part of this process includes intercepting small-offset stack loads and turning those into registers as well. Thus something like  (the patently silly and purely for example):

```
lwz eax,[ebp]
lwz ebx,[ebp+4]
add eax,[edx+0]
push eax 
lwz eax,[ebp+8]
add eax,ebx
pop ebx
add eax,ebx
```

cooks into something like (pretend internal registers are named *eg* r0..r16):

```
lw r3, edx
lw r1, ebp
lw r2, ebp+4 ; the constant '4' is usually stored as an immediate operand
add r1,r2
or r4,r1,r1 ;; move r1 to r4
lw r1, ebp+8
add r1,r2
or r2,r4,r4
add r1,r2
```

Of course a magically smart decoder (unlike the one that actually fits into transistor count) would collapse some of the unnecessary moves there, but the point I am making is that push/pop and stores/loads to `esp+(some small number)` are actually turned into shadow registers.

Comment: Thanks CrashWorks, great answer. Do you have a good reference for this? I have several architecture books and none of them mention this, but it was my suspicion that something like this was going on.

Comment: You can infer much of this information from chapter 2 of Intel's optimization manual ( http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/ ). You can also run some controlled experiments to try to figure out some of the "black box" internals. And you could always go poking through Intel's patents: after all, the purpose of a patent is that they have to tell you how it works! #5740414 might be a place to start.

Comment: Thanks, good points. First step is to order newer manuals than my 15 year old ones. :)

Comment: Yes, internally the x86 instruction stream gets decoded to something more like RISC, and it's the decoded trace that actually gets stored in the instruction cache and executed.

Comment: Very interesting answer. I'm wondering how that works out when considering parralel CPUS - how does the CPU "know" when to use an internal register, and when to do an actual memory/shared cache write? After all, a register write is by definition only visible to the core itself, but a memory write should at least eventually be globally visible, especially on x86 with its relatively strong memory access semantics.

Comment: This is truly great to know, I'm glad my search found your post. So, if I am interpreting this correctly if I have a function with a lot of state, more state than there are named registers. And even if the assembly generated is storing some of this state off to memory. I can still feel confident the processor is storing much of this in renamed registers rather than memory. Is this correct? In my case it's SSE code, and I have a lot of __m128i values.

Comment: This isn't quite right.  There's a stack engine that tracks changes to `%rsp` from push/pop / call/ret, so there isn't a 1-cycle dependency on the value or the stack pointer between every stack insn.  However, the actual values written/read by push/pop still go to RAM.  `pop` decodes to 1 uop: a memory read that can run on port 2 or 3 (SnB onwards).  There isn't a separate uop for modifying `%rsp`, because the stack engine handles that.  Register renaming doesn't have special stuff for `push`/`pop`.  There is store -> load forwarding, so a pop of a just-pushed value is fast.

Answer (score 4):

Two points:

(1) x86-64 doubles the number of registers to 16

(2) in modern x86 CPUs, an instruction that uses a memory location that is already in L1 cache is *nearly* as fast as the same operation with a register operand, so you can almost think of L1 as "register memory"

Comment: Re: (2) -- I've timed the latency of an L1 *hit* on my i7 at about 9 cycles, which (astonishingly) is actually slower than the Core Duo.

Comment: How did you time that ? It should only be 2 cycles on a Core i7, I think, which should not be a problem on a reasonably well scheduled instruction stream.

Comment: Re: (1), time to update my hardware manuals. I have 386, 486 and Pentium but nothing newer. Thanks to both you guys for the answers.

Comment: Sorry, I had my numbers mixed up in my notes -- that's actually the latency for the i5. We just used the cache latency tool from cpuid.com .

Comment: @Crashworks - +1 for the reference to cpuid.com, any other resources out there that you would suggest?

Comment: Mostly yes. But beware memory operands cannot be renamed and there might be read/write bottlenecks due to busy ports, L1 access sometimes can't match registers. But this only applies to the most optimized code, of course.

Comment: Forgot to mention, in cases where the data is re-read again right away store forwarding will make it very fast.

Comment: @alecco Frustratingly, on any *other* architecture, writing data to memory and then rereading it right away is very slow because it triggers a load-hit-store stall, clearing out the entire pipeline. This is a particularly severe problem on the PowerPC. It's an annoying case where what's optimal for one of our target platforms is exactly contradictory to what works on the others.

Comment: another point: the new AVX-512 also double the number of SIMD registers to **32** in 64-bit mode, beside doubling the size to 512 bits